# Is there a sheaf of categories $\text{QCoh}_X(1)$ analogous to $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, coherent-sheaves

Given a scheme $X$  and sum of divisors $D$, you can take the line bundle
$$\mathcal{O}_X(D)\ =\ \{\text{functions }f\text{ with [conditions on zeroes/poles]}\}\ \subseteq\ j_*\mathcal{O}_\eta\ =\ \mathcal{M}$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ is the sheaf of rational functions on $X$ and $j:\eta\to X$ is the generic point (or the union of generic points of the irreducible components). It satisfies $\mathcal{O}_X(D+D') =\mathcal{O}_X(D)\otimes\mathcal{O}_X(D')$. Moreover, under weak conditions these are the only coherent sheaves with an inverse under $\otimes$.

---

One categorical level up, you can consider sheaves of *categories* on $X$, with $\text{QCoh}_X$ being the analogue of $\mathcal{O}_X$.

My **question** is: what is the analogue "$\text{QCoh}_X(D)$" of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$?

---

If at all possible, the definition should mimic the above, defining it as a subsheaf of categories of $j_*\text{QCoh}_\eta$ defined by similar [conditions], and with the same identity for $D+D'$. Ideally, under the same weak conditions as above, these are the only invertible sheaves of categories.

Comment: Let me check if I understand a few things right: (1) You want to complete the analogy Picard group : Divisors :: Brauer group : (something), right?  (2) $\eta$ denotes the localization of $X$ away from the generic point and $j : \eta \to X$ is the inclusion, right? Some suggestions: (3) Is it clear what should happen in the affine case? (4) I might suggest editing the question title to make the question clearer.

Comment: I'd say the analogue is modules over Azumaya algebras (which are the invertible objects among quasi-coherent sheaves of categories).

Comment: @TimCampion (3/4) Understanding what $\text{QCoh}_X(1)$ is in the affine case should be the hard part of the question ($\text{QCoh}_X(-1)$ should presumably be the sheaves vanishing along $D$). (1) I have no idea how to generalise 
(G_m bundles <-> invertible sheaves)
to 
(BG_m gerbes <-> "invertible sheaves of categories")
but if you know how I'd love to hear!

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thanks - if you happen to know a reference for that I'd be happy to type up an answer here.

Comment: Concerning $\operatorname{QCoh}_\eta$ - maybe [my question about meromorphic bundles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/442844/41291) is related? There is [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/443180/41291) there...

Comment: I don’t think there’s a canonical gerbe associated to a divisor (which I think is what your question is asking for), rather there are many - the root stacks (gerbe of n-th roots of O(D) for given n, and the corresponding n-torsion invertible sheaf of categories), cf eg papers of Talpo and Vistoli

Comment: I think these results are originally due to Toën and Antieau-Gepner, but a convenient reference is section 11.5 in [Spectral Algebraic Geometry](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/SAG-rootfile.pdf). There is a bijection between invertible quasi-coherent sheaves of $\infty$-categories on a qcqs scheme $X$ and (derived) Azumaya algebras modulo Morita equivalence. You may also be interested in Remark 11.5.5.5: if $X$ is normal and noetherian, these are further equivalent to $B\mathbb G_m$-torsors.